# DroidParts Injection

Tags: java, android, sqlite, droidparts

When you start DependencyProvider it runs many times, show its in logcat:

```
Injector.inject():107
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.RuntimeException: No valid DependencyProvider method for 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase. 

Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the
database when it is no longer needed.
```

After a few seconds of the loop when the Activity is started for the app and log in I have logcat is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android / database / sqlite / $ SQLiteConnection Operation
```

Has anyone experienced this?

**Note**: Only the android version 4.1.2

Comment: Could you please provide a code snippet or a sample project to recreate this?